# How can I check whether we are in a transaction in SQLite?

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I have multiple functions which need to write to the database and they call each other. Until now, I have been using SAVEPOINT in order to allow nesting of transactions. The problem is that I need to get an EXCLUSIVE lock on the first SAVEPOINT instead of the default DEFERRED lock (this is neccesary to ensure that I wont get halted later by a SQLITE_BUSY). Therefore, I want to do something like follows:

```
int foo(sqlite3 *db){
    unsigned char wasIn = 1;
    if (!sqlite3_isInTransaction(db)){
         sqlite3_query(db, "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION");
         wasIn = 0;
    }
    ...do stuff....
    if (!wasIn){
         sqlite3_query(db, "COMMIT TRANSACTION");
    }
}
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7):

Have you checked this function?:

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/get_autocommit.html

> The sqlite3_get_autocommit() interface returns non-zero or zero if the
>   given database connection is or is not in autocommit mode,
>   respectively. Autocommit mode is on by default. Autocommit mode is
>   disabled by a BEGIN statement. Autocommit mode is re-enabled by a
>   COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

so if BEGIN was started then `sqlite3_get_autocommit()` will return 0